# Why are my Django form answers being saved multiple times and deleting the contents of another DB table?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm a complete beginner to Django and I've created a form of radio selects - each question is dynamically populated from the Questions table of my database. When the form is submitted, it should save various details of each question into the Scores table of the database. Scores has foreign keys to Questions on the id_question column and to the table Companies on id_company.

Currently I can show the correct values in a print statement, but saving them as instances has mixed results. Either each instance is saved multiple times with different values or every instance will take the value of one. I've tried moving the position of my save(), modifing the loops and how my data is stored, but the same problems keep repeating themselves. I have also tried accessing cleaned_data but it is usually empty.

On top of everything else, upon submission of the form and the saving of the scores, all of the question data is wiped from the database. The rows and id's are not deleted, but the other columns are given a null value.

I feel like I've approached this completely wrong, but I couldn't make sense of the Django documentation on forms and how to apply it to my project.

A new row should be created in the Scores table for each question of the form when the user submits. The following information should be included: id_company, id_question, answer, initialScore.

Here is my form.py (you can see some other things I've tried commented out):

```
from django import forms
from .custom_models import Questions, Scores, Companies
from django.utils import timezone
import re


class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        fields = ['questionnb', 'wording', 'answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3', 'answer4']

    # id_company = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    answers = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[('answer1', 'Answer 1'), ('answer2', 'Answer 2'), ('answer3', 'Answer 3'), ('answer4', 'Answer 4')],
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
        required=False
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['questionnb'].required = False
        self.fields['wording'].required = False
        # self.fields['id_company'].required = False

    def save(self, commit=True):  
        
        instance = super().save(commit=False)
        selected_answers = getattr(self, 'selected_answers', None)
        id_question = instance.id
        id_question_instance = Questions.objects.get(id = id_question)

        score = instance.score

        id_company = self.initial['id_company']
        id_company_instance = Companies.objects.get(id = id_company)

        details_list = []  # Initialize an empty list to store details

        for question_key, answer_value in selected_answers.items():
            questionnb = question_key
            answer = answer_value
            details_list.append(f"{questionnb}, {answer}")
            # Save the answer to Scores model
            if commit and answer is not None:
                Scores.objects.create(
                    id_company= id_company_instance,
                    id_question=id_question_instance,
                    answer=answer,
                    initialscore=score if answer == 'Oui' else 0,
                    createdat=timezone.now(),
                    updatedat=timezone.now()
                )
            if commit:
                instance.save()

        return instance

        # Print details outside the loop
        print(id_question, score, id_company_instance.id)
        for details in details_list:
            print(details)          
                
        # Save the answer to Scores model
        # if commit and answer is not None:
        #     Scores.objects.create(
        #         id_company= id_company_instance,
        #         id_question=question_instance,
        #         answer=answer,
        #         initialscore=question_instance.score if answer == 'Oui' else 0,
        #         createdat=timezone.now(),
        #         updatedat=timezone.now()
        #     )
        #     instance.save()

        # return instance
```

relevant code from views.py:

```
@login_required
def questionnaire(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        questions = Questions.objects.all().order_by('questionnb')
        questions_list = [QuestionForm(instance=question, initial={'id_company': request.user.company.id}) for question in questions]
        return render(request, 'form.html', {'questions_list': questions_list})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = [QuestionForm(request.POST, instance=Questions.objects.get(pk=question.id), initial={'id_company': request.user.company.id}) for question in Questions.objects.all()]
        post_data = QueryDict(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        # print(post_data)
        if all(form.is_valid() for form in forms):
            for form in forms:
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.selected_answers = {}
                    for questionnb, answer in post_data.items():
                        if questionnb != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' and questionnb != None:
                            form.selected_answers[questionnb] = answer
                    form.save()
        else:
            for form in forms:
                for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                    messages.error(request, f"Error in {field}: {', '.join(errors)}")
            return render(request, 'form.html', {'questions_list': forms})
    return redirect('dashboard')
       



# @login_required
# def questionnaire(request):
#     questions = Questions.objects.all().order_by('questionnb')
#     form = QuestionForm
#     questions_list = [QuestionForm(instance=question, initial={'id_company': request.user.company.id}) for question in questions]
#     if request.method == 'GET':  
#         return render(request, 'form.html', {'questions_list': questions_list})

#     if request.method == 'POST':
#         post_data = request.POST  # Use request.POST directly

#         for key, value in post_data.items():
#             if key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' and value == 'Oui' or value == 'Non':
#                 current_answer = value
#             if key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' and value == None:
#                     current_answer = 'Error'

#             # Update the 'answers' field for the current question form
#             form = QuestionForm(request.POST, instance=questions[key], initial={'id_company': request.user.company.id, 'question_id': questions[key].id})
#             form.cleaned_data['answers'] = current_answer if current_answer in ['Oui', 'Non'] else 'Error'

#             # Save the form and handle other logic as needed 
#             form.save()

#         return redirect('dashboard')
                    

    #     # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
    #     # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
    #     # user hits the Back button.
    #     return HttpResponseRedirect("dashboard")


            
        # post_data = QueryDict(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        # print(post_data)
        # forms = [QuestionForm(request.POST, instance=question, initial={'id_company': request.user.company.id, 'post_data': post_data}) for question in Questions.objects.all()]
        # if all(form.is_valid() for form in forms):
        #     for form in forms:
        #         form.save()

        #     return redirect('dashboard')
        # else:
        #     for form in forms:
        #         for field, errors in form.errors.items():
        #             messages.error(request, f"Error in {field}: {', '.join(errors)}")
        #     return render(request, 'form.html', {'questions_list': forms})
```

form.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Questionnaire {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'questionnaire' %}" class="w-5/6 flex flex-col text-justify">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1 class="text-center">Etat des Lieux</h1>
    {% for question in questions_list %}
        <div class="{% if question.questionnb.value|length > 3 %} ml-20 {%else%} ml-5 {%endif%} p-2 mb-2">
            <div class="flex mb-2">
                <p class="pe-2 text-base text-1.5xl font-medium text-gray-900">{{ question.questionnb.value }}</p>
                
                <p id="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}_">{{ question.wording.value }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-3">
                {% if question.answer1.value is not None%}
                    <input class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded" type="radio" id="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}_1" name="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}" value="{{ question.answer1.value|default_if_none:"" }}">
                    <label class="text-gray-700" for="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}_1">{{ question.answer1.value }}</label>
                {% endif %}

                {% if question.answer2.value is not None%}
                    <input class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded" type="radio" id="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}_2" name="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}" value="{{ question.answer2.value|default_if_none:"" }}">
                    <label class="text-gray-700" for="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}_2">{{ question.answer2.value }}</label>
                {% endif %}
                
                {% if question.answer3.value is not None%}
                    <input class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded" type="radio" id="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}_3" name="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}" value="{{ question.answer3.value|default_if_none:"" }}">
                    <label class="text-gray-700" for="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}_3">{{ question.answer3.value }}</label>
                {% endif %}

                {% if question.answer4.value is not None%}
                    <input class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded" type="radio" id="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}_4" name="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}" value="{{ question.answer4.value|default_if_none:"" }}">
                    <label class="text-gray-700" for="question_{{ question.questionnb.value }}_4">{{ question.answer4.value }}</label>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button class="btn-red-lg w-56 mx-auto my-6" type="submit" value="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

and my models:

```
class Questions(models.Model):

    questionnb = models.CharField(db_column='questionNb', max_length=10)  # Field name made lowercase.

    wording = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    answer1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    answer2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    answer3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    answer4 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    id_theme = models.ForeignKey('Themes', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_theme')

    createdat = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt')  # Field name made lowercase.

    updatedat = models.DateTimeField(db_column='updatedAt')  # Field name made lowercase.



    class Meta:

        managed = False

        db_table = 'questions'

        verbose_name_plural = "Questions"

class Scores(models.Model):

    id_company = models.ForeignKey(Companies, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_company')

    id_question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_question')

    answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    initialscore = models.IntegerField(db_column='initialScore', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    createdat = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt')  # Field name made lowercase.

    updatedat = models.DateTimeField(db_column='updatedAt')  # Field name made lowercase.



    class Meta:

        managed = False

        db_table = 'scores'

        verbose_name_plural = "Scores"
```

I realize that I haven't actually included the form that I defined in form.py in my template, but no matter what I did I could not make it show the questions and answers in the way that I wanted. Any help or explanation of why I'm having problems would be greatly appreciated! I've been stuck on this questionnaire for a week already and it's driving me crazy.